# Zynq PS_SRST pin is not connected in my design - can I still avoid locking the device down?

Tags: zynq

Unfortunately our board design is missing the PS_SRST pin connection on our Zynq XC7Z045 device - it is not connected (not pulled high or low).  As a result the device is (apparently) entering lock down during POR and is currently unusable.
Does anyone know if there is any way of successfully booting the device now?  As a last resort, we will need to remove the BGA from the board to insert a wire link and replace the device, but I would really rather avoid doing that if possible!

Comment: Drill carefully from the back (avoiding other tracks)?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, bit basic that!

I would note that there is a documented issue concerning the release of the reset signal after power up, and there is a window during which you MUST NOT release the reset or the thing will go into secure lockdown.

You need access to the reset, but you also need to ensure you do not release the reset in the critical window, see the TRM for details.

Comment: thanks - yes very unfortunate!   Looks like we have a way to fix it now though. 
The reset you are referring to that must not be released too early is the PS_POR reset, right?  PS_SRST could be left tied high according to the TRM.

Comment: Yea that's right, one of those cases where a reset supervisor is indicated.